# TinyMCE slider max and min value

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I want to change the font with a slider in my editor, however I cannot set max-ariavalue. The slider works with the default tinyMCE editor manager.

```
                // Open window
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'font resize',
                    body: [
                        {type: 'slider', name: 'size', label: 'Size', value: 50, max: 200}
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {
                        node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
                        execFontSize(e.data['size'], 'px', node);
                    }
                });
```

The max doesn't seem to work. I also tried "aria-valuemax" etc. Is it possible to change it, our do I have to "hack it" with JS?

Comment: The aria-* attributes do not control JavaScript behavior. They are only for accessibility.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the answer. I resolved it by adding a container type and using my own custom (html) range slider.

Comment: please post your solution so that someone else who stumbles across the same problem knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes you need are `minValue` and `maxValue` (as opposed to `min` and `max`).

For example:

```
editor.windowManager.open({ 
    title: 'font resize', 
    body: [ 
      {
         type: 'slider', 
         name: 'size', 
         label: 'Size', 
         value: 30, 
         minValue: 25, 
         maxValue: 50
      } 
    ], 
    ...  
});
```